# How to encode .wav format to Base64 for cloud speech http api android?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-speech-api

I am working on cloud speech api where i have to convert .wav file to encode String and then send it to http url for text for this i am using vip1beta http url . app is successfully getting .wav file but facing problem while encoding.

```
    {
"audio": {
 "content": ""

   },
 "config": {
  "enableAutomaticPunctuation": true,
  "encoding": "LINEAR16",
   "languageCode": "en-US",
    "model": "default",
  
       "audioChannelCount": 1  }
```

}

wav file

```
  private var mRcordFilePath =
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/audiowave.wav"

            val encodedString=EncodeUtils.encodeinBase64(mRcordFilePath)


 //encoding java class
```

public class EncodeUtils {

```
    public  static  String encodeinBase64(String audioFile){
     byte[] videoBytes;
       try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(audioFile));

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
            baos.write(buf, 0, n);

        byte[] toByteArray = baos.toByteArray();


        String video_str =  Base64.encodeToString(toByteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
       System.out.println("video array"+video_str);

       return video_str;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        println("Exception while encoding");
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return "";
}
```

}

encoded String

```
"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"
```

Comment: Which problem are you facing?

Comment: @blackapps conversion of wav to encode64 is not working?

Comment: What do you mean with 'is not working'?

Comment: @blackapps Question is how to convert audio file into Base64?

Comment: You are already doing that i would say. And not telling which problem you encounter.

Comment: @blackapps  i am converting audio file into base64 then i send it to post request  but not getting text from it ,the problem is with encoding ,so how to encode audio file properly thanks

Comment: Well whis problem do you have with encoding? Third time i ask. Come to the point.

Comment: @blackapps sorry for inconvenience , this is my last time i am mentioning you , i have also posted the encoded String above you can check it, this encoded String is not working in my case , if you have any better solution for encoding mention me 

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get that string from? How many characters/length? And where did you try to let it work? You are not giving any decent info about what you are doing while testing.